# how to save login user in create() of ModelSerializer of drf?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Models.py

```
class CustomTarget(models.Model):
target_red = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
target_amber = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
target_green = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
remarks = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectsMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
metric = models.ForeignKey(MetricsMaster, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

class Meta:
    db_table = 'custom_target'
    unique_together = (('user', 'project', 'metric'),)

Serializers.py

```
class CustomTargetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """

    """
    logger.info("Control entered into CustomTargetSerializer class")

    class Meta:
        model = CustomTarget
        fields = ('id', 'target_red', 'flag', 'user', 'project', 'target_amber', 'target_green','remarks', 'metric')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """

        :param validated_data:
        :return:
        """
        data = CustomTarget(target_red=validated_data["target_red"],
                            user=User(validated_data["user"]),
                            project=ProjectsMaster(validated_data["project"]),
                            target_amber=validated_data["target_amber"],
                            target_green=validated_data["target_green"],
                            remarks=validated_data["remarks"],
                            metric=MetricsMaster(validated_data["metric"]),
                            flag=True, )
        data.save()
        return data
```

views.py

```
@api_view(["PUT"])
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer,))
def custom_target(request):
    """
    To add new data and update existing data in custom_target table.
    :param request:
    :return:
    """
    logger.info("Control entered into custom_target")
    return_dict = dict()
    try:
        metric_data = request.data
        metric_config_obj = matrix_config_filter(metric_data)
        if metric_config_obj.exists() is True:
            if metric_config_obj[0].flag is True:
                custom_serializer = CustomTargetSerializer(data=request.data)
                custom_tar_obj = CustomTarget.objects.filter(metric=request.data['metric'])
                if custom_tar_obj.exists():
                    custom_serializer.update(validated_data=request.data, instance=custom_tar_obj)
                else:
                    if custom_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=ValueError):
                        custom_serializer.create(validated_data=request.data)
        return_dict["msg"] = "success"
        status_msg = status.HTTP_200_OK
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error from custom_target: %s" % e)
        return_dict["msg"] = "failed"
        status_msg = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

    return Response(return_dict, status=status_msg)
```

here,now i am giving hard coded user id,but i want to save user id of the login user in the create() of Serializer.
here user is saved in auth_user table and have foreign key relation with Custom_target table.
I tried so many things but i am not getting the request.user in Serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) along with [**`CurrentUserDefault`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault) as

```
class CustomTargetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    # your code
```

UPDATE-1 : Complete Serializer

```
class CustomTargetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = CustomTarget
        fields = ('id', 'target_red', 'flag', 'user', 'project', 'target_amber', 'target_green', 'remarks', 'metric')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = validated_data.pop('user')
        project = validated_data.po('project')
        metric = validated_data.pop('metric')
        instance = CustomTarget.objects.create(
            user=user,
            project=project,
            metric=metric,
            **validated_data
        )
        return instance
```

Comment: what i put in create function on at:   user = User(validated_data['user'])

Comment: or how can i save user data in user field through serializer with other fields?

Comment: its not working...i want to save current request user id in user field.

Comment: control is not going in the serializer create() function.nothing is happning.